# access to redux last state within listener function

Tags: react-redux, listener

i have a react functional component with a signal callback
how can i access to last redux state with in it:

```
const Demo = ()=>{
const data = useSelectore(s=>s.items);
const dispatch= useDispatch();
const listener = (x)=>{
console.log(data);//here i need access to last state
}
signalObj.on("EventName",listener);
//== init items
useEffect(()=>{
//=== after api calls
dispatch(initItems(items));
},[])

}
```

in above example items state will be init after first render with api call,
should i store items in use ref, is it the way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best approach i found was using redux thunk,
in that you can get last state and even have async function calls